# How to get comparison principle from contraction principle for PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

let $u$ and $v$ be two solutions to some PDE with initial data $u_0$ and $v_0$.
Is
$$|u(t)-v(t)|_{L^1} \leq |u_0-v_0|_{L^1}$$
a contraction principle?

I read that "contraction principle gives comparison principle" but I don't see how. A comparison principle would be: "if $u_0 \geq v_0$ then $u \geq v$".

What would this be called:
$$|(u(t)-v(t))^+| \leq |(u_0-v_0)^+|$$?

Basically my question is how to get a comparison principle from the contraction principle at the top?

Comment: What was the context of the statement "contraction principle gives comparison principle"? Source?

Comment: Im sorry I searched my history for the source but could not recover it. I think it is likely thought it was referring to my second dispalyed equation and not the first contraction.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the inequality $|(u(t)-v(t))^+| \leq |(u_0-v_0)^+|$ could be called, but it certainly implies the comparison principle. Indeed, if $u_0\le v_0$, then the right hand side is  zero, hence the left hand side is zero, hence $u(t)\le v(t)$.

Maybe it could be called the *comparison-contraction principle*.

Answer (score 0):

If the PDE conserves the integral over time, i.e. $\int u(t) \,dx = \int u_0 \,dx$ for all $t > 0$, and a technical condition on the domain of valid initial states is satisfied, then this indeed follows from Proposition 1 of the [paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1980-078-03/S0002-9939-1980-0553381-X/S0002-9939-1980-0553381-X.pdf) "Some relations between nonexpansive and order preserving mappings" of Crandall and Tartar.